# Computer laggs when editing build.gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx

I am using android studio 1.2.2. As I understand, build.gradle files manage the project settings. So if I want to add some extra "*.jar" files to my project dependencies, I would edit the gradle files.

So when I double click on the file to open it, in android studio, Android Studio freezes for several seconds. When the files is finally open, my CPU jumps to 100% and it stays there until I re-sync gradle again.

This problem has been persisting for a long time now. Its really annoying because I run off a quad core 2.2ghz processor and when it runs at 100% a it makes a really loud noise. Furthermore, Android Studio lags so much that it doesn't respond to my keystrokes anymore.

Just as a side note, my project is very large and has many gradle files due to the use of libGDX in my project.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.